# WIX - Remove registry key when checkbox checked during install

Tags: wix, custom-action

I've got a registry key which has been changed to a secure encrypted password by a program. However during upgrading this application we sometimes want to reset this password.

The installer writes the new password into our folder under SOFTWARE, however because the original password has been moved to VBO, it is impossible to encrypt and use the new password as the old password is still there.

Basically what I'm asking is how to remove a registry key (Which would be the key that has been moved to the VBO folder) based on a checkbox value in the WIX UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've actually finally managed to solve it.

What I've done is I created a component that then deletes the registry key if the checkbox in the UI is set.

```
<Component Id="RemoveReg" Guid="{F8ACDA4E-0641-4BCC-860A-DA1B1EB88702}">
   <Condition>RESETPASSWORD</Condition>
   <CreateFolder></CreateFolder>
   <RemoveRegistryKey Id="SQLPWREMOVE" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[Our Software]\VBO" Action="removeOnInstall" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Bingo! No custom actions needed.